# Java 7 on Windows 2000

Tags: operating-system, java-7, windows-2000

I have made a Java application with Java 1.7 my problem is that it is not running on windows 2000. It is saying me "this is not a WIN-32 Application".

how can I run my application on it?

Comment: Do you have Java runtime installed? How did you try to run the application?

Comment: @Juho No I run the application with a batch file. And in this batch file I start the application from a directory, in this directory is the java jre 
  `set CDJRE=java_vm\jre1.7\bin

start %CDJRE%\javaw.exe -Xmx512m -jar myapp.jar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a direct answer, but Java 7 (at least the Oracle implementation) is [not supported on Windows 2000](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html).

[Java 6 *did* support Windows 2000](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-135212.html).

Comment: are there other implementations of it?

Comment: @Neifen: Technically the OpenJDK is a separate implementations, but they are pretty much identical. I know of no other JVMs implementing Java 7 at the moment (which is to be expected, so shortly after Java 7 was defined/released).

Comment: Okey.. so I think I have to wait a little until I can programm with Java 7

Comment: @Neifen: out of curiosity: who is open enough to switch to Java 7 now but still working with a 10-year old OS?

Comment: I am open enougn to switch to Java 7 but the guy who need what I'm writing is not

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Win2k was a nice small OS to try the applications in the VM.